# Call function when browser is resized Angular 1.5 (components)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function that gets the width of a parent div, and calculates the total width of the child elements. It will apply a css class if the parent width is bigger than the total width of all child elements. It works on page load - but now I'm trying to figure out how to do it on browser resize.

This is my function in my controller...

```
public setCenterClass() {

    let parent =  document.querySelectorAll(".container")[0];
    let parentWidth = parent.clientWidth;
    let children = parent.children;
    let childrenWidth = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        childrenWidth += children[i].offsetWidth;
    }

    if (parentWidth > childrenWidth) {
        return 'center-content';
    }

    return;
}
```

and I call it from the parent div like this

```
<div class="container" ng-class="$ctrl.setCenterClass()" >...
```

It works, but if there is a better way then please let me know :)

Whats the best way to call setCenterClass() when the browser is resized?  All examples I have seen seems to use directives. I'm using Angular 1.5 with components and typescript. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to do this in javascript? I would use CSS, combining media queries (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to check screen width and flexbox (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) to set children width and alignment.

Comment: Actually, now that I read your question better, just FlexBox is fine: you can use justify-content:center or justify-content:space-around (based on what your class 'center-content' does) and, if the children are bigger than the parent, it won't have any visual effect.

Comment: Thanks Hank. I'm already using flex. The issue is there can be any number of child elements. So when the child elements can fit within the parent then i want to center it. If they dont, then they will be left aligned and the parent becomes scrollable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't really what you asked for, but I'll say it anyway: I think you should use **flexbox** + **justify-content** instead. Calling a function each time the user resizes the screen isn't good, and calling the function inside ng-class is even worse performance-wise since it would get called every time the model changes.

With flexbox, you can do this:

```
<div id="container">
   <div class="box">1</div>
   <div class="box">2</div>
   <div class="box">3</div>
   <div class="box">4</div>
   <div class="box">5</div>
</div>
```

With this CSS:

```
#container{
  height:800px;
  width:1200px;
  overflow-x:scroll;

  display: -webkit-box;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-around;
}

.box{
  height:300px;
  flex:0 0 300px;
}
```

This way, if the children all fit inside the parent, they will be centered and spaced, but if they overflow the parent, it will become scrollable.

Here's a [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/rC9QnjAZmH6RHgK81V8O?p=preview)

Comment: haha! Cool thanks.Will play a bit with it.  Only yesterday i tried this... https://embed.plnkr.co/nrOodSc8dezGbkqznCQh/